# Is it a good/bad practice for a service to send events to itself via an external queue?

Tags: design, event-sourcing, message-queue

Imagine there is an `Order` entity that has a lot of states and conditional transitions between them. At the moment it is stored in a relational DB.

There are multiple consumers of `Orders` that perform a `select for update` within a transactional method and then run a huge spaghetti of code to handle all the possible transitions and conditions within the same transaction. At first it was implemented this way to preserve the lock on the selected order so that it isn't processed twice.

I'm looking for a way to decouple all these transitions and conditions to make them more understandable. An event driven model might fit well, but I'm not sure how to implement it to assure every `Order` is processed only once in a multi-worker setup.

I thought I'd handle every `Order` in my service by publishing events to MQ/Kafka and then consume these events in the same microservice. This might ensure event persistence and a single processor handling the order at the moment.

Another way might be storing events in a DB table and running a scheduled task to retrieve them via `select for update`. It might work, but the idea of schedulers quering the DB for events seems quite odd to me.

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: What happens if another event happens before the self-event?

Comment: @user253751, not sure I understand the question. For every order there is a chain of events. Each of events changes order state and creates a new event (or finalises order). There may be a few 'out of nowhere' events like 'cancel' but as long as a single event for an order is processed at a time, this is easy to handle.

Comment: I mean what if the first half of your logic runs (due to e.g. external "submit order" event) and it queues a "mark as fulfilled" event for itself but in-between there is an external "cancel" event? Now you have an order that has been submitted and canceled and not marked as fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with consuming your own events is that every function call becomes a write to queue, read from queue and you have a bazillion event types.

Orchestrating events is hard. the more event types you add the harder it gets.

Messages should be fat, it sounds like you are sending a message with an id, and then hitting the database to retrieve the data for that id. Dont. Send everything in the message.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like the core of your problem is this:

> There are multiple consumers of Orders that perform a select for
> update within a transactional method and then run a huge spaghetti of
> code to handle all the possible transitions and conditions within the
> same transaction.

Would it be possible for you to refactor this code into several modules, for example could you create a:

- Payment processing module.
- Shipment module.

Note: I don't know your application / what makes sense for you - so I am using these as examples.

The core idea would be that once you have taken an order, you set a flag/state to "Processing Payment" at that time you can submit the order to payment processing module, if you chose to you could use a message queue for this - that way you can complete your initial transaction quickly.

Once the "Payment Processing" module is complete it can send a message back with the status of the payment - again you would start a transaction record the status of the payment and move on to the next step/state - for example submitting the order for shipment.

**Summary**

There are several ideas I am suggesting here:

- Don't hold database transactions open while waiting for external services.
- Modularize / segment your code into logical units.
- Use the core "order" object as a "workflow" so that you can track the high level status of the order - you don't need to keep the transaction open for all the low level work.
- Use asynchronous calls to decouple your modules - most likely this would be a queue, but other options may exist (for example background worker threads).